# Transition from a sign in ViewController to a UITabBarController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

So I am trying to transition from my sign in viewcontroller to my tabbarcontroller, after a successful login.

When I enter my login details and press the sign in button, I am redirected to the Appdelegate page with a signal SIGABRT error.

I tried using this code in my viewcontroller:

```
            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomViewController") as! CustomViewController
            self.present(mainPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: Screenshot of problem(1)]
[image: Screenshot of problem(2)]

Comment: What's in CustomViewController? If you're instantiating that one directly as a ViewController instead of as a UiTabBarViewController, I'm thinking you will need to add the Sub ViewControllers for each one of the Tabs manually. But it's difficult to be sure without looking at what you have in CustomViewController.

Comment: Oh I just took notice to that. Thank you! It's all good now :)

Comment: Ok, I will add this as an Answer, so that you can accept it and this will close this Question, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in CustomViewController? If you're instantiating that one directly as a ViewController instead of as a UiTabBarViewController, I'm thinking you will need to add the Sub ViewControllers for each one of the Tabs manually. But it's difficult to be sure without looking at what you have in CustomViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the application's `rootViewController` to the `UITabBarController` instance?

For example, this would set application's `rootViewController` to the tab bar controller:

```
let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomViewController") as! CustomViewController

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = mainPage
```